# Properties of a set $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ for which the statement $(\partial A)'=\partial(A')$ doesn't hold.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

I was pondering about the following question:

> Does the statement $(\partial A)'=\partial(A'),A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ hold?
>
> $A'$ denotes the set of limit points of $A$ and $\partial A$ is the boundary of $A$.

It doesn't hold as I found a counterexample: take $A=\Bbb Q.$ $$(\partial \Bbb Q)'=\left(\overline{\Bbb Q}\cap\overline{\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q}\right)'=\Bbb R,$$ while $$\partial(\Bbb Q')=\partial\Bbb R=\overline{\Bbb R}\cap\overline{\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb R}=\Bbb R\cap\emptyset=\emptyset.$$

I think we can generalize this in higher dimensions and do some variations of this with a proper subset of $\Bbb Q$.

> I was wondering how we could describe all sets for which the statement doesn't hold. Do they have to be dense in the ambient space?

Comment: Note that the boundary is already closed - taking the closure will not change it. So you are asking about sets where the boundary and the boundary of the closure disagree - it is elementary to check $\partial A \supseteq \partial\overline A$. If the inclusion is strict this means there is some point in $\partial A$ so that any approximating sequence automatically lies in $\overline A$, ie this point is in the interior of $\overline A$. In the end:
$$\partial A - \partial\overline A = \partial A \cap \mathrm{int}(\overline{A})$$

Comment: @s.harp, I denoted the set of limit points of $A$ by $A',$ not the closure, so, I'm asking about the boundary of the set of limit points vs. set of limit points of the boundary. But, to your comment, I see $\partial(\overline A)=\overline A\cap\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus \overline A}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus A}=\partial A$ and how $\partial(\overline A)\subset\partial A$ and $\partial(A)\cup\operatorname{Int}(A)=\partial(\overline A)\cup\operatorname{Int}(\overline A)$ would imply $\partial A\cap\operatorname{Int}(\overline A)\ne\emptyset.$